# when i add sum(order_amount)/100.0 as "Money_amount" is wrong

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

```
select
    date(update_time) as dt,
    count(DISTINCT agent_id) as trans_users,
    count(order_no) as trans_cnt,
    sum(order_amount)/100.0 as Money_amount
from report_mongo.ng_t_offline_merchant_acq_order
where child_trans_type in ('71','73','74','76','e8')
and order_app_type=1
and order_status=2
group by 1
order by date(update_time) desc
```

```
[Err] ERROR:  Numeric data overflow (addition)
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Numeric data overflow (addition)
  code:      1058
  context:   
  query:     299910919
  location:  numeric_bound.cpp:180
  process:   query3_580_299910919 [pid=20157]
  -----------------------------------------------
```

I do not know it before, I have used this code there are a lot days, but today I can success operate

Comment: That's not a Postgres error message

Comment: Smells like Redshift

Comment: yes this is Redshift ,in postgresql ,i have used this code there are a period but today is not  ok

Comment: looks like an Amazon Redshift error

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the column to a larger capacity data type e.g.

```
select
    date(update_time) as dt,
    count(DISTINCT agent_id) as trans_users,
    count(order_no) as trans_cnt,

    sum(cast(order_amount as numeric(16,2))/100.0 as Money_amount

from report_mongo.ng_t_offline_merchant_acq_order
where child_trans_type in ('71','73','74','76','e8')
and order_app_type=1
and order_status=2
group by 1
order by date(update_time) desc
```

Comment: still not ok bro
[Err] ERROR:  Numeric data overflow (result precision)
DETAIL:  
  -----------------------------------------------
  error:  Numeric data overflow (result precision)
  code:      1058
  context:   64 bit overflow
  query:     299981662
  location:  numeric_bound.cpp:112
  process:   query3_840_299981662 [pid=32799]
  -----------------------------------------------

Comment: This error occurs when a value exceeds the limits set by the precision and scale of a numeric data type. Precision represents the total number of digits including those on both sides of the decimal point, while scale represents the number of digits on the right side of it.  we cannot see you data `numeric(16,2)` was a guess, the maximum precision is 38